# Duplicate menu items with ActionBarSherlock and Fragments in older versions of Android (pre 3.0)

Tags: android, menu, tabs, android-fragments

I am using `Fragments` and `ActionBarSherlock` with tabs.  My menu items are acting very strangely in older versions of Android.  At first the menu acts normally, but when I change tabs (which changes fragments, though it's the same activity), it appears that the menu is being duplicated, because the icons (normally somewhat transparent) become very white, like they're being drawn several times.  Then they start acting strangely, I have to wait a long time after selecting anything for it to execute.  Any buttons that don't change the activity or fragments remains selected (highlighted).

Since this doesn't happen in the newer OS (4.0 +), I'm not sure what is causing it. I'm guessing it has something to do with the tabs and fragments. Whenever I change tabs, I remove all fragments if they aren't null, and replace the containers with new fragments.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you insert another fragment the menu items don't just vanish. So perhaps try to call `menu.clear()` in `onCreateOptionsMenu`.